# go to other section in same page in angularjs ui.router environment

Tags: angularjs

First, I want to achieve go to sections on the same page. Traditionally I can do this by:

```
<a href="#about">about</a>

<a name="about"></a>
```

This approach is not work because my page implement ui router, when I defined `href="#about"`, it detect as otherwise url, so will be redirect to wrong state.

From other source I get insight about `multiple views` in ui.router, so I designed config like this:

```
.state('landing', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
                ""                  : { templateUrl: "tpl/landing/index.html"},
                "header@landing"    : { templateUrl: "tpl/landing/header.html"},
                "about@landing"     : { templateUrl: "tpl/landing/about.html"},
                "contact@landing"   : { templateUrl: "tpl/landing/contact.html"},
                "section-a@landing" : { templateUrl: "tpl/landing/section-a.html"},
                "section-b@landing" : { templateUrl: "tpl/landing/section-b.html"},
                "services@landing"  : { templateUrl: "tpl/landing/services.html"},
                "footer@landing"    : { templateUrl: "tpl/landing/footer.html"}
        }
    })
```

Content of `tpl/landing/index.html` is:

```
<div ui-view="header" autoscroll="true"></div>
<div ui-view="about" autoscroll="false"></div>
<div ui-view="contact" autoscroll="false"></div>
<div ui-view="section-a" autoscroll="false"></div>
<div ui-view="section-b" autoscroll="false"></div>
<div ui-view="services" autoscroll="false"></div>
<div ui-view="footer" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

In `multi state` ui.router we can go to other state by defined `ui-sref="astate"`. How about in multiple views? how to go to other view in same state?

Comment: what does `go to other view` even mean?

Comment: Now web page focus on header, when I click about menu, it will be focused on about below

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be solved using `$anchorScroll`. See here for more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

In their example, you can see:

```
<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
   <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
   <a id="bottom"></a> You're at the bottom!
</div>
```

Then inside the `gotoBottom()` function they use:

```
$location.hash('bottom');

// call $anchorScroll()
$anchorScroll();
```

This will scroll to the div whose id is `bottom`. Hopefully that helps you.